# Android and XML Parser stax-1.2.0.jar versus using the source

Tags: java, android, xml

I found the source code and jar files for Java StAX [here](http://stax.codehaus.org/).  The files all have "Copyright 2004 BEA Systems, Inc." in them.  Bea was bought by Oracle in 2008.

I put the two jar files in the libs directory and included them in the build path.  But then I get a lengthy error message about using someone else's code and system package names followed by a Dalvik error that basically says I can't use jar files that have Javax.xml.xxxx package names.

If I instead put the source code into my src directory and refactor all of the javax. directories to something else, it works.

Would I be violating any copyright laws using the source code and modifying it to work with Android?  What if I modify the code to bring it up to current Java standards and remove unused code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work.  Here is what I did:

1. Create a new Java project in Eclipse, extract the source code file **stax-src-1.2.0.zip** (downloaded from Codehaus), and import the source code into your new project.
2. Refactor all of the javax.xxxxx folders.  I added "bea." in front of all of them, like "bea.javax.xml".  Make sure none of the source files show an error.  I had to open one of them and manually and change its import (by addeding "bea." to it).
3. Right-click on src and select Export... "Java - JAR File", and click next.
4. In "Select the resources to export", select both **.classpath** and **.project**.  Then have these options selected:

   - Export generated class files and resource
   - Export java source files and resources
   - Chooses a destination.  The libs directory of the Android project is where it will go.
   - Compress the contents of the JAR file
   - Add directory entries

Once the JAR file is in the libs folder of the Android project, you will be able to use.  I didn't need to add it to the build path.

Answer (score 0):

A copyright statement doesn't mean you can't copy or modify the source; it means that you can only do what the license permits you to do. So you need to find out what the license for these files permits. They are almost certainly issued under some kind of open source license, which probably permits the kind of usage you have in mind.

This is not legal advice!

Comment: Yea!  In the source code zip there is a text containing an Apache License that says: "Redistribution. You may reproduce and distribute copies of the
      Work or Derivative Works thereof in any medium, with or without
      modifications, and in Source or Object form, provided that You
      meet the following conditions: ....".

Comment: I was wondering: who/what is Codehaus?  Do they have a right to make the source available?  Why doesn't Oracle make the source available, if it is open source?  Is that separate license file legit or added by someone else?  Thanks!

Comment: I am going to use my app for getting a real job, and I don't want to break any rules.

Comment: Codehaus is a site that hosts open source projects, rather like sourceforge or github. I can't tell you what rights they have (I assume the question was rhetorical anyway). And I can't tell you why Oracle does what it does, that has been a mystery to me for 30 years.

Comment: Thanks.  I am new to Android, Java, and the concept of open-source.  I have a ways to go before I can be rhetorical.